# Mixing normal string with f-string in line continuation

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

Is it ok to mix normal string and new f-string like this:

```
import timeit

format = """
def format(name, age):
    return (
        f'He said his name is '
        f'{name} and he is '
        f'{age} years old.'
    )
""", """
def format(name, age):
    return (
        'He said his name is '
        f'{name} and he is '
        f'{age} years old.'
    )
"""

test = """
def test():
    for name in ('Fred', 'Barney', 'Gary', 'Rock', 'Perry', 'Jackie'):
        for age in range (20, 200):
            format(name, age)
"""

for fmt in format:
    print(timeit.timeit('test()', fmt + test, number=10000))

[out]:
3.4188902939995387
3.3931472289996236
```

Is this ok to use or it is not considered best practice to mix normal string and f-string?

Comment: This is not about opinion but is about the known shortcoming of different methods

Comment: It's fine - inside a string, `f` is just another character. Just as long as you don't try to use `str.format` at the same time.

Comment: @MadPhysicist FYI Rahul *is* OP.

Comment: @TylerH. And apparently I'm illiterate. Thank you for the catch :)

Comment: @Rahul. My apologies for being an idiot. Could you stick that comment into the question? It would make it much more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opinion-free question here is what does it **mean** to “compile-time concatenate” formatted string “literals” that are really runtime expressions?  The language reference merely [says that you **can**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation).

Experimentation with `dis` reveals that even a lone f-string is decomposed into interstitial string literals and formatting expressions (which are compiled to the new `FORMAT_VALUE` opcode, not turned into calls to `str.format` or so).  Each f-string is handled this way **separately** (prior to concatenation, so `f"{x" f"}"` is invalid).  The prefix and suffix string literals, if any, that *result* from this decomposition are then concatenated with adjacent normal string literals (or those produced by adjacent f-strings).  Finally, the equally new `BUILD_STRING` opcode is used to join the pieces efficiently.  Note that this means that your two `format` functions compile to **identical** bytecode and any timing differences are just noise.

From this (implementor’s) perspective, the rules are obvious; from the user’s perspective, formatting occurs, intuitively, only inside `f"…"`.  It’s a matter of taste whether to write `f"v={{{x},{y}}}\n"` or `"v={" f"{x},{y}" "}\n"`, but I can certainly conceive of cases where the latter would be preferable.  So long as you’re willing to point people to this question if they have doubts about the semantics, I’d say that’s enough to make the **half-opinion** answer “yes, it’s OK”.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't knew this and it will be really helpful.